# Class design - create a object from String data?

Tags: java, class, constructor

I am working on simple application of Universal Turing Machine. I have a data to create machine from, my questions is not about UTM I would like to illustrate it only on this app. I need to create an object from String data, e.g. this method create one transition function of my UTM:

```
public static Transition createFromData(String data) {

    Transition trans = new Transition();
    String[] dataSplitted = data.split("1");
    trans.setInputState(new State(dataSplitted[0]));
    trans.setInputSymbol(dataSplitted[1]);
    trans.setNewState(new State(dataSplitted[2]));
    trans.setNewSymbol(dataSplitted[3]);
    trans.setMovement(Movement.getByCode(dataSplitted[4]));

    return trans;

}
```

Is it good idea (from class design perspective) to have such methods in Transition class or should I separate them to another / tool classes? What is bets practice for this issue?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid design pattern, called the "static factory pattern". I would recommend using some sort of "parser" interface and injecting an implementation dependant on the type of data - it's not good to couple the class to it's representation in the data. Having said all that this question is not suitable for this forum - it is a) opinion based and b) asking for code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tools/utils classes always remind me of structured programming ;) but would help if you just had a constructor on the Transition class the would receive the raw data and create a new transition object with that. Since you will be creating a new transition each time you find some raw data the best fit is in the constructor (or maybe in a factory method, but that is another discussion)

Comment: *(or maybe in a factory method, but that is another discussion)*: it's not another discussion. The OP specifically asked if it would be a good idea to have this method in the Transition class itself, making it a factory method.

Comment: I prefer the OPs static factory pattern to your suggestion of sticking it all in a constructor. As @JBNizet points out that _is_ the discussion here.

Answer (score 0):

what about having this method in a another class for eg: RawData, which will have static factory methods for creating different objects from data.

In your case you can have one method will will return `Transition` object and then you can have multiple methods and each return a different object depending upon how data is organized / represented in that object.